# The path-connected field is just $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: topological-groups, topological-rings

A topological ring is a ring $R$ which is also a topological space such that both the addition and the multiplication are continuous as maps.

$F$ is a topological field, if $F$ is a topological ring, and the inversion operation is continuous, when restricted to $F\backslash\{0\}$.

If $F$ is a path-connected field, then $F$ must be topologically isomophic to the real number field $\mathbb{R}$ or the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Certainly not. Any field withindiscrete topology will do. A less contrived example: $\Bbb C(T)$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen However, a discrete topological space is totally disconnected.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: How do you topologize $\mathbb{C}(T)$?

Comment: Here is a rather exotic example. Connected fields of arbitrary characteristic: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250524535